# How many strings of eight English letters are there that contain exactly one vowel, if letters can be repeated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many strings of eight English letters are there that contain exactly one vowel, if letters can be repeated?

Comment: What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: sir i m new here . So take care about thiz in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of 5 vowel 1 vowel.

$\binom{5}{1}$

7 letters can out of 21 consonants can be choosen.

$21^7$

And 1 vowel can be on any 8 places in 8 ways.

Total = $\binom{5}{1} * 21^7 * 8$

Comment: in other cases we don't need to multiple like u did 8 in thiz ...i know it is stupid question ..but cn u clear it more.

Comment: Suppose you have 5 places __, __, __, __, __ and you have one thing where you can place it? You simply say I have 5 options or ways. So similarly in your case its 8.

Comment: cn u explain thiz question :->How many bit strings of length n contain exactly r 1s?

Comment: Ok I try send me link.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $21^7\times8\times\binom{5}{1}$. This is because we can choose one vowel in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways. The other $7$ can be filled with $21$ letters(consonants) with repitition. The $8$ accounts for the permutations of the vowels and consonants.